# Knowledge for writing a compiler for Win32

Tags: compiler-construction

I have created an interpreter for my programming language (educational) and now I'd like to go one step further and create a compiler for it. I know that this is pretty hard work.

What I already know is:

- I need to translate my input language to assembler

A lot, isn't it? Now what I don't know is:

- What assembler do I need to create Win32 PE executables like, for example, Visual Studio does?
- What about file headers?

I'd prefer not to use MASM but it seems like I'll have to.

- How to combine the assembler with my compiler?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler

Answer (score 1):

You don't strictly need to translate your code to assembly; you can get away with translating it to *any* language that can compile to a native executable.

Let's look at an extremely simple example.  Say I had some worthless imaginary language (hereafter called Adder) where the input file consisted of any number of lines, each containing a space-delimited list of integers. The output is the sum of each line.

So for an input file

```
1
1 2 3
200 50 6
```

the output would be

```
1
6
256
```

You can write an *interpreter* for Adder in a single line of Ruby:

```
puts($_.split.map(&:to_i).inject(0, :+)) while gets
```

What if I wanted to translate an input program to a standalone Ruby script?  Simple:

```
while line = gets
  num = line.split.map(&:to_i).inject(0, :+)
  puts "puts(#{num})"
end
```

Output:

```
$ ruby adder2rb.rb nums.txt 
puts(1)
puts(6)
puts(256)
$ ruby adder2rb.rb nums.txt  | ruby -
1
6
256
```

Okay, now what if we want to translate this to something that actually compiles to a native executable -- say, C?  We hardly have to change anything:

```
puts '#include <stdio.h>'
puts 'int main() {'

while line = gets
  num = line.split.map(&:to_i).inject(0, :+)
  puts "  printf(\"%ld\\n\", #{num}L);"
end

puts '  return 0;'
puts '}'
```

Session output:

```
$ ruby adder2c.rb nums.txt
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("%ld\n", 1L);
  printf("%ld\n", 6L);
  printf("%ld\n", 256L);
  return 0;
}
$ ruby adder2c.rb nums.txt | tcc -
$ ./a.out
1
6
256
```

(Note here that `tcc` is [Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/), which may be very useful to your project if you want end users to be able to generate executables from your generated C files.)

Want to translate to another high level language?  How about Haskell?

```
$ cat adder2hs.rb
puts 'main = do'

while line = gets
  num = line.split.map(&:to_i).inject(0, :+)
  puts "  print #{num}"
end
$ ruby adder2hs.rb nums.txt
main = do
  print 1
  print 6
  print 256
$ ruby adder2hs.rb nums.txt | runghc
1
6
256
```

Of course, the code translator for any language with more than one construct will be significantly more complext than the above examples; however, the basic idea remains the same that you will have general templates that you follow for your output language.

Now if you decide that you still *really* want to generate assembly instead of high-level code, you aren't restricted to a single implementation there either.  Somewhat easier than straight assembly is translating to a virtual machine's bytecode.  [MSIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tkafs1%28VS.71%29.aspx) would give you .NET executables, or you could use [LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html)'s code generation facilities.  If Java is more your thing you can emit [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine) bytecode. One slightly less common choice would be [Parrot](http://www.parrot.org/).

Of those VMs, AFAIK only LLVM will generate actual native executables, but maybe that isn't your top concern right now.